# Randomising conditions with alternating order in PsychoPy

Tags: python, psychopy

I have a simple experiment with 8 different trials that I wish to present only once without repeat; participants are asked to 'solve' a numeric sequence where 4 sequences have a solution (S) and 4 are unsolvable (U).

Thus, I have 8 trials: `S1, S2, S3, S4, U1, U2, U3, U4`.

I want to present the trials so that they alternate - but randomizing the order of S and U, while maintaining the alternating pattern.

For example, a valid result might be `S3, U2, S2, U4, S4, U1, S1, U3`.

The only solutions I can come up with is to try and shuffle the order of the trials in the excel file and then combining them so they alternate - this doesn't seems very elegant though.

Is there a simple way to implement this within the builder or by adding a code component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to combine (interleave) two lists in an alternating fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678869/pythonic-way-to-combine-interleave-two-lists-in-an-alternating-fashion)

Answer (score 0):

Uses prior answer [on list conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355442/converting-a-list-of-tuples-into-a-simple-flat-list) and concept of [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
import random as r 
a = ["s1","s2","s3","s4"]
b = ["u1","u2","u3","u4"]
r.shuffle(a)
r.shuffle(b)
trialList = [tr for pr in zip(a,b) for tr in pr]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `zip` (or `itertools.izip`) and then flatten the result using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.  Using `zip` takes multiple sequences and creates a new sequence where each item contains the corresponding elements from the original sequences.  In your case, it will create something like `[(S3, U2), (S2, U4), (S4, U1), (S1, U3)]`.  You can then flatten using the `chain` function to get the `[S3, U2, S2, U4, S4, U1, S1, U3]` sequence you want.  `shuffle` randomizes the order of the two sequences *in-place*, while `list` converts the iterator that results from `chain` into a list:

```
from itertools import chain, izip
from random import shuffle

solvable = [s1, s2, s3, s4]
unsolvable = [u1, u2, u3, u4]

shuffle(solvable)
shuffle(unsolvable)

trials = list(chain.from_iterable(izip(solvable, unsolvable)))
```